# Sphere inside ball

Tags: geometry

I have a cuboidal shoe box $(1000 \times 1250 \times 2450 )$, and I place a tennis ball of maximum possible volume that fits inside a box. What is the smallest possible distance between a corner of the box and a point on the surface of the ball?

Comment: Do you mean sphere inside box?

Comment: The diameter of the largest sphere that can fit inside the box is equal to to the smallest side. Best to then draw a diagram to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The International Tennis Federation requires that a tennis ball have a diameter of no more than 2.70 inches.  As jim suggested, the largest sphere you can put in such a box is 1000 (of whatever units those numbers are in) but it probably is not a tennis ball!

Answer (score 1):

If my math is correct, the shortest possible distance should be $366.0254038...$.

Since the smallest dimension of the cuboidal shoe box is $1000$, then the radius for the tennis ball would be $500$. (diameter of $1000$).

To get the shortest distance from a corner of the box to the surface of the ball, conceptually the ball should be placed in a corner of the box. The center of the ball is $500$ above the bottom of the box and $500$ from each side of the box. (The sides that the ball is touching) Using the Pythagorean Theorem in 3 Dimensions you find the distance from the corner of the box to the center of the ball to be $$\sqrt{ 500^2+500^2+500^2} = 866.0254038$$ Subtract the radius of the ball from the found value and you get $366.0254038$.